# ¿Por qué al ejecutar una consulta, me muestra registros duplicados?

Tags: php, mysql

**Edito: Ya lo resolvi miren los comentarios, solo lo dejo como una autorespuesta en caso me vuelva a pasar**.

---

La verdad parece sencillo de responder pero, no veo ninguna solucion, ya probe todo y aun no encuentro cuál es el problema.

**CONTEXTO**: Necesito mostrar las firmas(que son las iniciales de los nombres) en un documento que genero en pdf. Para que me entiendan, básicamente estoy mostrando la asistencia de unos miembros que realizan una reunión. A la reunion pueden llegar miembros y/o suplentes de algun miembro

Tengo una consulta mysql simple

```
SELECT mc.firmaMiembro FROM detalleMiembro dm 
            INNER JOIN miembroComite mc ON dm.codMiembro=mc.idMiembroComite
            INNER JOIN acta a ON dm.codActa=a.idActa
            WHERE dm.codActa=".$idActa." AND 
            mc.codCalidadMiembro!=1 AND
            mc.codCalidadMiembro!=5 AND
            mc.codCalidadMiembro!=6 AND 
            mc.codCalidadMiembro!=7 AND
            dm.codMiembro=mc.pert
```

**Explicación:** Lo que hace esta consulta es buscar todas las firmas de los que asistieron a la reunion `WHERE dm.codActa=".$idActa."`, `$idActa` trae el numero de reunión y como otros filtros solo aparecen las firmas que tienen cierto tipo de calidad(debido a restricciones requeridas). Y la ultima linea es para filtrar solo a los **miembros** que asistieron, es decir, no debe mostrar a los suplentes.

Al ejecutarlo en el phpmyadmin el resultado es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo cual me da un resultado correcto. Hasta aqui la consulta se ejecuta correctamente. Ahora, cuando quiero mostrar este resultado con PHP, me los duplica y no entiendo porqué, ya que ejecuto el query aparte(es decir, no esta dentro de un while, ni de un for como para que se duplique por algo así).

Este es el codigo que utilizo para mostrar el resultado:

```
     // RECORREMOS LAS FIRMAS CORRESPONDIENTES

        $firm = "";

        $conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $password) or die ("No se ha podido conectar al servidor de Base de datos ");

        $db = mysqli_select_db($conexion, $basededatos) or die ( "Upps! Pues va a ser que no se ha podido conectar a la base de datos" );       

        $sql = "SELECT mc.firmaMiembro FROM detalleMiembro dm 
                INNER JOIN miembroComite mc ON dm.codMiembro=mc.idMiembroComite
                INNER JOIN acta a ON dm.codActa=a.idActa
                WHERE dm.codActa=".$idActa." AND 
                mc.codCalidadMiembro!=1 AND
                mc.codCalidadMiembro!=5 AND
                mc.codCalidadMiembro!=6 AND 
                mc.codCalidadMiembro!=7 AND
                dm.codMiembro=mc.pert GROUP BY dm.codMiembro";


        $firmas = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql) or die ( "Algo ha ido mal en la consulta a la base de datos");
        
        while ($dotad = mysqli_fetch_array($firmas)) {
            $firm .='""""""""""""'.$dotad['firmaMiembro'];
        } 
$firm.=$firm.'"""""""""""" RUBRICADAS.-';
```

Lo cual a la hora de imprimirlo me da este resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aun si utilizo `if` en vez de `while`, me sigue imprimiendo doble el primer registro

¿Porque me imprime doble al querer mostrarlo con php?

Comment: La respuesta deberías colocarla en la zona de respuestas por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo resolvi: el problema es una linea de codigo, dejo esta pregunta como una autorespuesta y tambien para hacer conciencia de fijarse bien en los puntos o punto y comas, porque son traicioneros `$firm.=$firm.'"""""""""""" RUBRICADAS.-';` habia un `.` antes de `=` lo cual hacia que se me duplicara la información